# Vertically center two minipages inside enumerate environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I am trying to achieve this layout:
[image]

I tried the following things:

- Two centered minipages within `\item` command, **Problem:** "(a)" is centered with the two minipages:

[image]

- A large top-aligned minipage within the `\item`, which then contains two centered sub-minipages. The same visual problem as before, but I can at least manually shift the block up by using a negative `\vspace`

Is there a way to solve this elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the boxes, and adjust the right hand side with `\raisebox`

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}



\begin{enumerate}
\item 


\sbox0{\parbox[t]{.45\linewidth}{%
$\begin{aligned}[t]
x+y+z+a&=b\\
&\rightarrow c\\
&\rightarrow d\\
&\rightarrow e\\
&\rightarrow f
\end{aligned}$}}
\sbox2{\parbox[c]{.45\linewidth}{%
    \begin{tabular}[c]{c|cc}
      a&b&c\\\hline
      1&2&3
    \end{tabular}}}
\usebox{0}\hfill
\raisebox{-.5\dp0}{\usebox{2}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```